# Android - Error while trying to login with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am unable to log into the facebook SDK if the Facebook app is installed on my phone.

[image: Error]

I succeed in logging in if I disable the Facebook app through settings. The SDK then opens a webview and it works perfectly. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any logs, so I don't have much more information than this.

If anyone has an idea of what could be happening, it would be greatly appreciated. Note that I do succeed in logging in if the app is not installed, so I don't think it's a configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If login success in `webview`  and not working in native installed `Facebook` app

So problem with your `HashKeys` not match with `Facebook` app.

The error occurs because of **invalid hash key**.

Generate key and change it